# Resistor identification on a shunt PCB of a battery manager

Tags: batteries, resistors, identification, thermistor, varistor

A battery manager (Victron Energy BMV-602S) has a shunt which has a small PCB attached to it. The manager is able to monitor two batteries - "advanced" monitoring of a leisure battery (B1) and "basic" monitoring of a starter battery (B2.)

The board of my shunt is lost, so I reconstructed the original circuit and will etch my own PCB. The board consists of:

- RJ25 connector (to the management unit)
- two terminals for positive poles of the batteries (+B1 and +B2)
- two contact pads (to each end of the shunt)
- two capacitors (C1 and C2)
- one resistor (R1)

The resistor (marked R1 on the PCB) does not look like a "usual" resistor. It seems to be a sort of non-linear thermistor or varistor (my guess.)

A photo of an original shunt with a board is attached at the end, the resistor is in the red box. The resistor has a label "R010 B7V" on it.

- What type of resistor is it?
- What function does it have?
- What resistor can I use as a replacement?

**Attachments:**

Original shunt with a board (red box: resistor R1):

[image: Original Shunt with a board]

Close-up picture of the resistor R1:

[image: Close-up resistor]

Reconstructed circuit of the PCB (red box: resistor R1, green: battery positive terminals, blue: RJ25 connector):

[image: Reconstructed circuit]

General connection guide of the shunt and the monitoring unit for two batteries:

[image: BMV quick start guide]

Comment: Please show the marking on the assumed resistor. Is it a round disc? Diameter / thickness?

Comment: It is, as shown on the photo of the PCB, the part R1. The Marking is "R010 B7V". I assume R010 is the resistance value, but I cant identify the type of resistor.

Comment: Yes, I read that already, but still think it is not just a resistor. On a photo of the marking there might be some hint like manufacturer sign or so... and the size and form still is interesting. Even if R1 is printed on the PCB it must not be so - not that unusual to me. Maybe we understand from it's function. So what is pin 1 of this connector doing? Need to look at victron docs...